# Unusual calculus problem

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Let $f(x,y)$ be defined for $(x,y) \in ([-1, 1], [-1,1])$, with that said $f(x,0)\equiv C$ for $x \in [-1,1]$ and for any $t \in [0,1], y \in [-1,1]: f(t, y) \equiv C$. Here $C$ states for const.

Prove that $f(x,y)$ is constant on the whole 2D section defined.

Literally came across this kind of tasks for the first time yesterday, and even don't know what to start with..
Will appreciate any help

Comment: Something wrong with your statement. If $f(t,y) =C$ for all $t$ and $y$ then $f$ is a constant. What is there to prove?

Comment: the function definition clearly states that $\forall t,y \in [0,1], f(t,y) = C$.Did you mean to say that $f'(t,y) = C$?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy sorry, mistyped

Answer (score 1):

Choose any $x,y\in[0,1]$. First apply the second condition then the first condition.
$$f(x,y)=f(x,0)=f(0,0)$$
Hence proved.

Geometrically, it says that if a given function is constant on every vertical line and is also constant on the $x$-axis, then this is a constant function.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps what you are assuming is that $f$ is a constant on the bottom edge of the square and also a (possibly different) constant on each vertical line. In that case $f(x,y)=f(x,0)$ which shows the constant value on the bottom edge is the only value $f$ can take.